# Best way to bind the data from Asp.net web serivce to client App

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I hava to bind data from Asp.net webservice to Windows Forms app.

Here is my code:

```
PGPInfo[] _personGroupInfoObj = webObject.GetAllPGPMobInfo();
```

I also tried:

```
 dataset ds=webObject.GetallLocations();
```

Both are taking 1 minute to bind 10000 records.

I have 20 methods like this in my app.  I want to speed up this binding process to boost up the performance.

Is there another way to bind the data?

Comment: try implementing paging in you methods so that payload of 10000 records is not to be on the wire in a one call

Comment: Hi Shoaib,can u give clear explaination

Comment: @Balu What Shoaib is trying to say is that since your data is coming via a web-service, you are transferring a lot of data "across the wire" at once, and this will almost certainly be slow.  If you handle the data in batches (or "pages") then you should be able to provide the client with some intermediate results and make the application feel faster.

Comment: Sorry to ask u this.I am new to Programming.How to handle the data in batches?

Comment: do you have code/access to your web service? what kind of technology it is built on? what is the underlying data source for that web service?

Comment: Paging will have to be done on service side. Service must allow parameters such as pagiSize and pageIndex. If Balu doesnt control web service, he cannot really avoid getting all data in one call